# Dapper & SQLinq Package Deferred / Buffer

Tags: dapper

I am using Dapper with the [SQLinq Nuget package](https://github.com/crpietschmann/SQLinq).

Here is some sample code I am using.

Dapper with SQLinq runs the query before I run a .ToList() (for example).

I know with Dapper you can specify "buffer" to make it run deferred, but I do not see how to apply that with the SQLinq NuGet package for Dapper.

```
using (var sqlCnn = base.GetConnection())
  {
   var viewData = sqlCnn.Query(from s in new SQLinq<Week_Returns_stats_V>(). . .

public SqlConnection GetConnection(bool mars = false)
{
    if (_sqlCnn != null)
    {
       if (_sqlCnn.State != ConnectionState.Open) CloseConnection();
    }

    if (mars)
    {
      var scsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_cnnString)
     {
         MultipleActiveResultSets = true
     };               
    }

    _sqlCnn = new SqlConnection(_cnnString);
    return _sqlCnn;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to include buffered after the query.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Query<T>
(this IDbConnection dbconnection, 
SQLinq<T> query, 
IDbTransaction transaction = null, 
bool buffered = true, 
int? commandTimeout = default(int?), 
CommandType? commandType = 
default(CommandType?)) where T : new();

var viewData = sqlCnn.Query(from s in new SQLinq<Returns_stats()
              select new
                {
                AVGPercentReturnX100 = s.AVGPercentReturnX100,
                PercentProfitableX100 = s.PercentProfitableX100
                }, buffered:true).AsEnumerable()
```